# Facing issue in Magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9, order-grid

We have added the column in Order Grid --- we have named as order items and below is the code, it was working fine suddenly its appearing in the backend (the menu is missing) can you let me know if any issue :-

```
class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Item_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
{

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->setId('sales_item_grid');
    $this->setUseAjax(true);
    $this->setDefaultSort('created_at');
    $this->setDefaultDir('DESC');
    $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
}

/**
 * Retrieve collection class
 *
 * @return string
 */
protected function _getCollectionClass()
{
    return 'sales/order_item_collection';
}

protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());




    $collection->getSelect()

    ->joinLeft(array('order'=>'mglr_sales_flat_order'),
                'order.entity_id = main_table.order_id',
                array(
                        'order_increment_id'=>'order.increment_id',
                        'order_created_at'=>'order.created_at',
                        'order_base_tax_amount'=>'order.base_tax_amount',
                        'order_discount_amount'=>'order.discount_amount',
                        'order_base_subtotal'=>'order.base_subtotal',
                        'order_grand_total'=>'order.grand_total',
                        'order_shipping_description'=>'order.shipping_description',
                        'order_shipping_amount'=>'order.shipping_amount',
                        'order_customer_id'=>'order.customer_id',
                        'order_status'=>'order.status',
                        'order_coupon_code'=>'order.coupon_code',
                        'order_store_id'=>'order.store_id',
                        'order_customer_note'=>'order.customer_note',
                    )
                )

    ->joinLeft(array('payment'=>'mglr_sales_flat_order_payment'),
                'order.entity_id = payment.parent_id',
                array(
                        'payment_method'=>'payment.method',
                        'trans_status'=>'',
                        'last_trans_id'=>'payment.last_trans_id'
                    )
                )
    ->joinLeft(array('billing'=>'mglr_sales_flat_order_address'),
                'order.entity_id = billing.parent_id AND billing.address_type = "billing"',
                array(
                        'billing_email'=>'billing.email',
                        'billing_firstname'=>'billing.firstname',
                        'billing_lastname'=>'billing.lastname',
                        'billing_company'=>'billing.company',
                        'billing_street'=>'billing.street',
                        'billing_city'=>'billing.city',
                        'billing_region'=>'billing.region',
                        'billing_country_id'=>'billing.country_id',
                        'billing_postcode'=>'billing.postcode',
                        'billing_telephone'=>'billing.telephone',
                        'billing_street2'=>'',
                        'billing_diff'=>'',
                    )
                )
    ->joinLeft(array('shipping'=>'mglr_sales_flat_order_address'),
                'order.entity_id = shipping.parent_id AND shipping.address_type = "shipping"',
                array(
                        'shipping_email'=>'shipping.email',
                        'shipping_firstname'=>'shipping.firstname',
                        'shipping_lastname'=>'shipping.lastname',
                        'shipping_company'=>'shipping.company',
                        'shipping_street'=>'shipping.street',
                        'shipping_city'=>'shipping.city',
                        'shipping_region'=>'shipping.region',
                        'shipping_country_id'=>'shipping.country_id',
                        'shipping_postcode'=>'shipping.postcode',
                        'shipping_telephone'=>'shipping.telephone',
                    )
                )
    ;


    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}

protected function _prepareColumns()
{

    $payments = Mage::getSingleton('payment/config')->getActiveMethods();
    $methods = array();
    foreach ($payments as $paymentCode=>$paymentModel)
    {
        $paymentTitle = Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/'.$paymentCode.'/title');
        $methods[$paymentCode] = $paymentTitle;
    }

    $this->addColumn('order_customer_id', array(
        'header'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('CustomerID'),
        'width' => '30px',
        'type'  => 'text',
        'filter' => false,'index' => 'order_customer_id',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('payment_method', array(
        'header'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('OrderGateway'),
        'width' => '50px',
        'type'  => 'options',
        'options' => $methods,
        'filter' => false,'index' => 'payment_method',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('order_increment_id', array(
        'header'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Order #'),
        'width' => '50px',
        'type'  => 'text',
        'filter' => false,'index' => 'order_increment_id',
    ));

    if (!Mage::app()->isSingleStoreMode()) {
        $this->addColumn('order_store_id', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Purchased From (Store)'),
            'filter' => false,
            'type'=>'options',
            'index'     => 'order_store_id',
            'options' => array(1=>'Main Website-Main Website Store-Default Store View')
        ));
    }

    $this->addColumn('order_created_at', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('OrderDate'),
        'index' => 'order_created_at',
        'type' => 'datetime',
        'width' => '100px',
        'filter_condition_callback' => array($this, '_dateFilter'),
    ));

    $this->addColumn('order_base_tax_amount', array(
        'header'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('TotalTax'),
        'width' => '50px',
        'filter' => false,'index' => 'order_base_tax_amount',
        'type'  => 'currency',
        'currency' => 'base_currency_code',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('order_shipping_amount', array(
        'header'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('TotalDelivery'),
        'width' => '50px',
        'filter' => false,'index' => 'order_shipping_amount',
        'type'  => 'currency',
        'currency' => 'base_currency_code',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('order_discount_amount', array(
        'header'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('TotalDiscounts'),
        'width' => '50px',
        'filter' => false,'index' => 'order_discount_amount',
        'type'  => 'currency',
        'currency' => 'base_currency_code',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('order_base_subtotal', array(
        'header'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('SubTotal'),
        'width' => '50px',
        'filter' => false,'index' => 'order_base_subtotal',
        'type'  => 'currency',
        'currency' => 'base_currency_code',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('order_grand_total', array(
        'header'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('TotalCost'),
        'width' => '50px',
        'filter' => false,'index' => 'order_grand_total',
        'type'  => 'currency',
        'currency' => 'base_currency_code',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('billing_email', array(
        'header'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('BillingEmailAddress'),
        'width' => '30px',
        'type'  => 'text',
        'filter' => false,'index' => 'billing_email',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('billing_firstname', array(
        'header'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('BillingFirstName'),
        'width' => '30px',
        'type'  => 'text',
        'filter' => false,'index' => 'billing_firstname',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('billing_lastname', array(
        'header'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('BillingLastName'),
        'width' => '30px',
        'type'  => 'text',
        'filter' => false,'index' => 'billing_lastname',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('billing_company', array(
        'header'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('BillingCompanyName'),
        'width' => '30px',
        'type'  => 'text',
        'filter' => false,'index' => 'billing_company',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('billing_street', array(
        'header'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('BillingAddress1'),
        'width' => '30px',
        'type'  => 'text',
        'filter' => false,'index' => 'billing_street',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('billing_street2', array(
        'header'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('BillingAddress2'),
        'width' => '30px',
        'type'  => 'text',
        'filter' => false,'index' => 'billing_street2',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('billing_city', array(
        'header'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('BillingTown'),
        'width' => '30px',
        'type'  => 'text',
        'filter' => false,'index' => 'billing_city',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('billing_region', array(
        'header'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('BillingCounty'),
        'width' => '30px',
        'type'  => 'text',
        'filter' => false,'index' => 'billing_region',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('billing_country_id', array(
        'header'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('BillingCountry'),
        'width' => '30px',
        'type'  => 'country',
        'filter' => false,'index' => 'billing_country_id',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('billing_postcode', array(
        'header'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('BillingPostCode'),
        'width' => '30px',
        'type'  => 'text',
        'filter' => false,'index' => 'billing_postcode',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('billing_telephone', array(
        'header'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('BillingTelephone'),
        'width' => '30px',
        'type'  => 'text',
        'filter' => false,'index' => 'billing_telephone',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('billing_diff', array(
        'header'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('DifferentAddress'),
        'width' => '30px',
        'type'  => 'text',
        'filter' => false,'index' => 'billing_diff',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('shipping_email', array(
        'header'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('ShippingEmailAddress'),
        'width' => '30px',
        'type'  => 'text',
        'filter' => false,'index' => 'shipping_email',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('shipping_firstname', array(
        'header'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('ShippingFirstName'),
        'width' => '30px',
        'type'  => 'text',
        'filter' => false,'index' => 'shipping_firstname',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('shipping_lastname', array(
        'header'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('ShippingLastName'),
        'width' => '30px',
        'type'  => 'text',
        'filter' => false,'index' => 'shipping_lastname',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('shipping_company', array(
        'header'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('ShippingCompanyName'),
        'width' => '30px',
        'type'  => 'text',
        'filter' => false,'index' => 'shipping_company',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('shipping_street', array(
        'header'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('ShippingAddress1'),
        'width' => '30px',
        'type'  => 'text',
        'filter' => false,'index' => 'shipping_street',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('shipping_street2', array(
        'header'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('ShippingAddress2'),
        'width' => '30px',
        'type'  => 'text',
        'filter' => false,'index' => 'shipping_street2',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('shipping_city', array(
        'header'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('ShippingTown'),
        'width' => '30px',
        'type'  => 'text',
        'filter' => false,'index' => 'shipping_city',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('shipping_region', array(
        'header'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('ShippingCounty'),
        'width' => '30px',
        'type'  => 'text',
        'filter' => false,'index' => 'shipping_region',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('shipping_country_id', array(
        'header'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('ShippingCountry'),
        'width' => '30px',
        'type'  => 'country',
        'filter' => false,'index' => 'shipping_country_id',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('shipping_postcode', array(
        'header'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('ShippingPostCode'),
        'width' => '30px',
        'type'  => 'text',
        'filter' => false,'index' => 'shipping_postcode',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('shipping_telephone', array(
        'header'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('ShippingTelephone'),
        'width' => '30px',
        'type'  => 'text',
        'filter' => false,'index' => 'shipping_telephone',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('order_shipping_description', array(
        'header'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('DeliveryMethod'),
        'width' => '30px',
        'type'  => 'text',
        'filter' => false,'index' => 'order_shipping_description',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('order_coupon_code', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Discounts'),
        'filter' => false,'index' => 'order_coupon_code',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('order_customer_note', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('CheckoutFields'),
        'filter' => false,'index' => 'order_customer_note',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('order_status', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Status'),
        'filter' => false,'index' => 'order_status',
        'type'  => 'options',
        'width' => '70px',
        'options' => Mage::getSingleton('sales/order_config')->getStatuses(),
    ));

    $this->addColumn('last_trans_id', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('TransactionID'),
        'filter' => false,'index' => 'last_trans_id',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('trans_status', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('TransactionStatus'),
        'filter' => false,'index' => 'trans_status',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('product_id', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('ProductID'),
        'filter' => false,'index' => 'product_id',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('name', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('ProductName'),
        'filter' => false,'index' => 'name',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('sku', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('ProductCode'),
        'filter' => false,'index' => 'sku',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('options', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('ProductOptions'),
        'filter' => false,'index' => 'options',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('price', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('ProductPrice'),
        'filter' => false,'index' => 'price',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('discount_amount', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('ProductDiscount'),
        'filter' => false,'index' => 'discount_amount',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('product_delivery', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('ProductDelivery'),
        'filter' => false,'index' => 'product_delivery',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('qty_ordered', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('ProductQuantity'),
        'filter' => false,'index' => 'qty_ordered',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('original_price', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('ProductRRP'),
        'filter' => false,'index' => 'original_price',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('item_id', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('OrderItemID'),
        'filter' => false,'index' => 'item_id',
    ));

    if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/order/actions/view')) {
        $this->addColumn('action',
            array(
                'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Action'),
                'width'     => '50px',
                'type'      => 'action',
                'getter'     => 'getId',
                'actions'   => array(
                    array(
                        'caption' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('View'),
                        'url'     => array('base'=>'*/sales_order/view'),
                        'field'   => 'order_id',
                        'data-column' => 'action',
                    )
                ),
                'filter'    => false,
                'sortable'  => false,
                'filter' => false,'index'     => 'stores',
                'is_system' => true,
        ));
    }
    $this->addRssList('rss/order/new', Mage::helper('sales')->__('New Order RSS'));

    $this->addExportType('*/*/exportCsv', Mage::helper('sales')->__('CSV'));
    $this->addExportType('*/*/exportExcel', Mage::helper('sales')->__('Excel XML'));

    return parent::_prepareColumns();
}

protected function _prepareMassaction()
{
    // $this->setMassactionIdField('entity_id');
    // $this->getMassactionBlock()->setFormFieldName('order_ids');
    // $this->getMassactionBlock()->setUseSelectAll(false);

    // if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/order/actions/cancel')) {
    //     $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('cancel_order', array(
    //          'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Cancel'),
    //          'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/massCancel'),
    //     ));
    // }

    // if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/order/actions/hold')) {
    //     $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('hold_order', array(
    //          'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Hold'),
    //          'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/massHold'),
    //     ));
    // }

    // if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/order/actions/unhold')) {
    //     $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('unhold_order', array(
    //          'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Unhold'),
    //          'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/massUnhold'),
    //     ));
    // }

    // $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('pdfinvoices_order', array(
    //      'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Print Invoices'),
    //      'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/pdfinvoices'),
    // ));

    // $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('pdfshipments_order', array(
    //      'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Print Packingslips'),
    //      'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/pdfshipments'),
    // ));

    // $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('pdfcreditmemos_order', array(
    //      'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Print Credit Memos'),
    //      'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/pdfcreditmemos'),
    // ));

    // $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('pdfdocs_order', array(
    //      'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Print All'),
    //      'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/pdfdocs'),
    // ));

    // $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('print_shipping_label', array(
    //      'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Print Shipping Labels'),
    //      'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order_shipment/massPrintShippingLabel'),
    // ));

    return $this;
}

public function getRowUrl($row)
{
    if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/order/actions/view')) {
        return $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/view', array('order_id' => $row->getId()));
    }
    return false;
}

public function getGridUrl()
{
    return $this->getUrl('*/*/grid', array('_current'=>true));
}

protected function _dateFilter($collection, $column) {

    $_filter_data = $column->getFilter()->getValue();
    $from = $_filter_data['from'];
    $from = date('Y-m-d h:i:s',$from->getDate()->toValue());
    $to = $_filter_data['to'];
    $to = date('Y-m-d h:i:s',$to->getDate()->toValue());             
    if($_filter_data["from"]!=''){
        $collection->getSelect()->where('order.created_at >= ?', $from);           
    }

    if($_filter_data["to"]!=''){
        $collection->getSelect()->where('order.created_at <= ?', $to);
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Comment: Please show us `adminhtml.xml`, that file is responsible for displaying menu.

Comment: this location is in app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/etc/adminhtml.xml

Comment: Thanks Adarsh, was able to slove it was the problem with the menu